# Is there any way to access a private variable in a parent from the child inheriting from it?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, inheritance

Let's say I'm building an ERC1155 contract, and I incorporate OpenZeppelin's [`ERC1155Supply`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Supply.sol). That, at least as of the current `master`, has the following:

```
mapping(uint256 => uint256) private _totalSupply;
```

Now let's say I want to access that mapping directly. I obviously can't do:

```
_totalSupply[i]++
```

or something like that, since the whole point of `private` is that it [can't be seen by the child](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/cheatsheet.html?highlight=private#function-visibility-specifiers), but I *did* think that something like:

```
ERC1155Supply._totalSupply[i]++
```

would work, but unfortunately the compiler doesn't seem to agree with me.

```
TypeError: Member "_totalSupply" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract ERC1155Supply).
```

Is there any way to access the mapping from the child contract? If there isn't, is there some kind of other solution? Since it isn't a `public` variable, I can't even override it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can alter the parent contract I can advise you to use the `internal` access modifier. Then it works out of the box.

Otherwise implement a `set` function in you parent contract. For example:

```
uint256 private number;

function setNumber(uint256 num) public{
    number = num;
}
```

Then in the child contract:

```
function setNumberChild(uint256 num) public{
    parent.setNumber(num);
}
```

You could use `internal` for the `set` function in the parent contract as well.

Comment: the problem here is that I'm inheriting a contract from OZ, so I don't want to modify it - my last resort would be to literally copy the code into my contract and modify it (ERC1155Supply isn't very big), but I'm hoping to avoid it, and there would be other cases where it would be super unwieldy

Comment: (and OZ didn't put a setter on this one)

Comment: @TheRenaissance Yeah it kindof makes sense that there is no setter for this `ERC1155Supply`. Changing to what I indicated probably leads to some vulnerabilities. From what I see their contract isn't designed to facilitate incrementing the totalSupply at a later point.

Comment: or rather it only increments through `_beforeTokenTransfer`, so if I wanted to make an unsafe (but gas cheaper) mint function, I'm stuck